# Magento theme displays errors and responsive display after refresh

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, jquery

We have a Magento webshop **(1.9.3.2)** with **Ultimo theme**, which appears to have some strange problem in a few browsers - we've discovered it's only on Chrome and Opera so far. When you first watch the website (https://www.tuinkussengigant.nl) in Chrome, it displays correctly with no `JS errors`. When you refresh the page, the website changes to some weird `responsive mobile view` and suddenly `JS errors` show up too.

We've looked at the page resource of both versions (the correct one and the weird responsive view), but both of them are exactly the same. We have no idea where to look for what's wrong.

The only thing we could already find, was the `JS noconflict` thing, but that's already in one of the included .js files Magento `minified`, so that's not the case either.

Can somebody please push us into the right direction of where to look on how to solve this problem? Has it something to do with the async of the js file, since it's only after a refresh and not when the page is first loaded with CTRL+F5 for example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out there was a problem with the order of the JS files being included. First, I disabled JS merge for the specific store view. The responsive view was solved, but the JS errors not yet. To fix those, I removed the 'async' from prototype.js file.